# Push data from TextFormField Flutter to Listview.builder Items when form field is validated

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, form-fields

I have form field : [image: FormField]

This form field will collect all the data from my client.
Each of these field is specific and I want push the entry of each of these field into a ListView.builder according to the name of the field.
For example the field " Alias" has to be push into the listview.builder that you can see above, and the others fields has to be push to another listview.builder in order to build an address book.
this is my code for listview.builder.
Please I accept suggestion how to to that thanks:

```
Container(
            height: 1000,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, int) {
                return Card(
                    color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                    elevation: 15,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Card(
                            color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                            child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                child: Icon(Icons.location_on,color: Colors.white,size: 25,)),

                          ),
                          Text('User id № $int',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          Text(userDestinationFullName,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),),),
                          Text(aliasName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent),),
                          Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.white,)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ));
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: do you want alias to appear as fixed header ?

Comment: No no, Alias is a dynamic Name that user will use to recognise more quick all the details of the customer. as above into the list where you see +Alias... instead of alias will be subsitute with the name of Alias that who fill the form will write.
all the fields that will be filled must be exported into listview.builder to build a new list where all the data ( or at least the data I want ) of the form will be shown.

Comment: I still didn't get your question. Can you elaborate on how u want the listview ?

Comment: is that when you click on the name card , u want to see all the details about the name ?

Comment: when you are submitting the form store the form data in a map<> and then use list builder on that map

Comment: can you share the form code ?

Comment: Please check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok
the list view is the code I posted above
in such listview I need to have the data that I retrieve from the formfield which the customer will fill up.
For example:
In the field "Alias" into the form customer will write " Home "
this "Home" has to be shown into the listview
Customer will also write as "Nome e Cognome" the full name of the for example "Mario Rossi", then Mario Rossi has to appear into the list view in a single row.
this is the screenshot of the list view.
https://ibb.co/LN2nVtk
as you can see the horizontal list where is + alias, Alias... has to be substitute with the written field that customer fill in the form
vertical ListView has rows with several text, each of these text is a field into the form, so each of these field has to be substitute with the written filled into the form

Comment: yes i got it, can you share the code that builds the form ? Then i can provide a solution

Comment: yes I provided the code for the form tell if it is enough

Comment: can you share your project github link. Then i can edit it to solve your query

Comment: Instead of using use normal ListView and inside it use List tiles to display your answers,

Comment: Ok let me push it on github

Comment: Ok here is the direct link to the form code:
https://github.com/wytex/speedooTest/blob/master/lib/pages/fillingshipment.dart

Comment: did you see github project?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SkD3yTdcdUv4J7la9mM9H22tOiyF4fkc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: made some changes

Comment: Thanks! will check and let you know!

Comment: Hello thanks for the things done:
Now the output is that when form is submitted for each form field it created a single row...
What I want is different, for each form field for example - Alias - Full name in the first row... in the second row alwais alias and fullname but different because user will fill the form again... and so on.
So for each row we will have same form field " Alias and Full Name and second row the same etc....

Answer (score 0):

This is just a field to a form
for example Full name field once filled the content has to be push into the listview as shipmentFullName

```
Widget FullName() {
  return TextFormField(
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Nome e Cognome obbligatorio';
      }
      return null;
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF1f2032), fontSize: 14),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
      filled: true,
      labelText: 'Nome e Cognome',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF1f2032)),
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.person_add,
        color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
        size: 17,
      ),
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
      ),
      hintText: 'Nome e Cognome del Destinatario',
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 35.0),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF1f2032), width: 1.5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```